# Why does a SwiftUI animation behave and align differently on iOS and macOS?

Tags: swiftui

I've started a new multiplatform project (Xcode 12.4). I wrote a short animation that I pasted below.

Given this simple swift code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MuiltiPlatApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.blue)
                    .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                    .opacity(Double(2.0 - animationAmount))
                    .animation(
                        Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0)
                            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    )
            )
            .onAppear{
                self.animationAmount += 1
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

While it works well on iOS, unfortunately running the same code on macOS looks different.

The result is:

[image: Text]

I tried several alignments but nothing helped. Could you tell me why do the two appearances different? How could I fix the problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you, but what pawello2222 posted is works. I haven't recovered yet.. ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to specify the animation `value`:

```
.animation(
    Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0)
        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false),
    value: animationAmount
)
```

---

From the documentation:

```
/// Applies the given animation to all animatable values within this view.
///
/// Use this modifier on leaf views rather than container views. The
/// animation applies to all child views within this view; calling
/// `animation(_:)` on a container view can lead to unbounded scope.
///
/// - Parameter animation: The animation to apply to animatable values
///   within this view.
///
/// - Returns: A view that wraps this view and applies `animation` to all
///   animatable values used within the view.
@inlinable public func animation(_ animation: Animation?) -> some View
```

```
/// - Parameters:
///   - animation: The animation to apply. If `animation` is `nil`, the view
///     doesn't animate.
///   - value: A value to monitor for changes.
///
/// - Returns: A view that applies `animation` to this view whenever `value`
///   changes.
@inlinable public func animation<V>(_ animation: Animation?, value: V) -> some View where V : Equatable
```

As you can see, by default SwiftUI *applies the given animation to all animatable values within this view*.

However, when you pass the `value`, then SwiftUI *applies `animation` to this view whenever `value` changes*.

Comment: Jesus .. thank you very much! It's work.. And that's okay.. well.. but why does it work well on iOS than? You saved my night!!

Comment: @los.adrian It only happened to work in this particular case - try rotating the device for example...

Comment: I swear I've tried it! I even ran it on an iPad and rotated on it too and the behaviour was good there too.. only not on macOS. I never thought of this solution. Thanks again!

Comment: One more note! If I leave the .animation code snippet at the Circle() and increase the self.animationAmount with the withAnimation() method, it still works fine.

Comment: @los.adrian It's hard to say what exactly are *all animatable values* for a given view. If you use `animation(_:value:)` you can be sure it animates only when the `value` changes. Otherwise you may encounter unexpected issues like the one in your question.